# Missing (404) justified-nav.css file for Bootstrap/Google Charts API

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an older Google Charts API HTML template with the following dependencies in the header:

```
 <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet'>
 <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css" rel='stylesheet'>
 <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
```

I am getting a 404 for the justified-nav.css file, does anyone know what a replacement might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/justified-nav.css
```

For `3.3` and `4 Alpha` respectively.

Although I believe the latest version has justified navs **[built-in](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#fill-and-justify)**, using the `.nav-justified` class. Just remember to set a class of `nav-item` on the children in order to actually justify them:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
</nav>
```